# How to round a double value to a selected number of decimals in .NET?

Tags: .net, double, rounding

I use an acceleration sensor to calculate the current accelerations and it returns the double value.

However I would like to compare the current acceleration with value 9.8. Before doing that i have to round the value received from the sensor so the question is: How to round a double value to a selected number of decimals in .NET?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Math.Round(number, precision)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx

Answer (score 4):

[Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx) - i.e.

```
double val = Math.Round(current, 1); // 1dp
```

Comment: arghhh beat me by 50 seconds :-)