# How to discard the garbage values of a double?

Tags: double

I have a long double value x. which value is actually 3.00. But in the debugger I see the value is 3.00000000000012312414 that is some garbage value after 13th decimal point. How do I discard this garbage? If I had to print, I can just write `printf("%.10llF",x);` but I have to compare if the number is integer. One way to compare is `long long xt = x; if(x == xt)` I will just take the values before 12th place. But for the garbage values, this isn't working. How do I do that?

Comment: No, its value is actually 3.00000000000012312414. Where did you get the mistaken idea its value is 3.00?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/693493/62576 and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not garbage it is how floating point numbers are stored.  To compair floating point numbers you always need to define an acceptable error e.  When you compare x to y if the abs(x -y) < e the numbers are equal.  Also take a look at this [document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

you should use some epsilon to compare floating point values.

`3.00000000000012312414` can **not** be represented just as `3.000000000000000000` because computer representation of numbers is not that precise.
If it should be exactly 3, you have to declare it as integer.

Comment: While you should always use an epsilon to compare floating-point values, both 3.00000000000012312414 and 3.000000000000000000 can be represented exactly in floating-point. The poster is probably expecting different floating-point calculations to be represented identically.

Comment: In just `double` it can't be.